# Unity and ArCore: How to place an object at real world location?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, location, arcore

I'm working on an AR project for school.

I need to place an object at a certain location (school gate) and I need to see it with an AR camera.

I can get the location of the user, but how can I place the object?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an augmented image for the gate to get the location of the gate. Because every time you run the application your origin will be your device position. So the physical location of the gate will be relative to location where you started your app and changes every Session. Then what you can do is following:

```
    public GameObject YourGameObject;
    private List<AugmentedImage> m_TempAugmentedImages = new List<AugmentedImage>();
    Session.GetTrackables<AugmentedImage>(m_TempAugmentedImages, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);

    foreach (var image in m_TempAugmentedImages){
          Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
          var obj = Instantiate(YourGameObject,anchor.transform);
          obj.transform.parent = anchor.transform;         
    }
```

Eventually what this piece of code does is find the trackable augmented image, creates an anchor at the center of that image and instantiate your object at that location. Last it anchors your object to a physical location.

Comment: its not exactly what i need . I try something markerless or augmented imageless . Because i want to see the object without seeing the gate .

Comment: Yes but how do you plan to initially find the location of the door then?